Javax Inject Not Working for InjectingMocks
I'm trying to test a service that injects its dependencies with @Inject. But for some reason I can't use InjectMocks for other dependencias inside the test. My service Example:
@Component
public class UpdateFileService {

   @Inject
   FolderRepository folderRepository;
   @Inject
   PermissionDTOConverter permissionConverter;

}

The PermissionDTOConverter is a class that I don't want to stub.
So I want to make It to work like this:
public class UpdateFileSecurityServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private FolderRepository folderRepository;
    @InjectMocks
    private PermissionDTOConverter permissionDTOConverter;
    @InjectMocks
    private UpdateFileSecurityService service;
}

And whenever I try to test a method It throws a NullPointerException because It says that the DTO does not exists. But if I use construtor injection like this>
public class UpdateFileSecurityServiceTest {
        @Mock
        private FolderRepository folderRepository;
        @InjectMocks
        private PermissionDTOConverter permissionDTOConverter;
        @InjectMocks
        private UpdateFileSecurityService service;
        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            service = new UpdateFileSecurityService(folderRepository, permissionDTOConverter);
        }
}


You haven't added @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) to your test so the mockito annotations are ignored

Tried that but nothing changed... I found out that the PermissionDTOConverter is @Lazy annotaded... Does that change something?

Where is definition of documentRepository?

Sorry my mistake...

This question is similar to: Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Does your PermissionDTOConverter require any other mocks to be injected? If not, why are you annotating it to inject other mocks? If you need a real instance, create it yourself: private PermissionDTOConverter permissionDTOConverter = new PermissionDTOConverter();

Mockito is designed to inject dependencies into a single class instance that you want to test. The notion that you are injecting dependencies into a dependency is counter to the intent of Mockito.  However, I've had some success with this.
Per javadoc for InjectMocks

Again, note that @InjectMocks will only inject mocks/spies created using the @Spy or @Mock annotation.

So, PermissionDTOConverter must be annotated as a Spy in order for InjectMocks to inject the PermissionDTOConverter into UpdateFileSecurityService while also injecting dependencies into PermissionDTOConverter.
@InjectMocks
@Spy
PermissionDTOConverter permissionDTOConverter;

Unfortunately, that is not enough to actually get it to inject because the permissionDTOConverter reference will be injected into the UpdateFileSecurityService instance before it is instantiated.  This is where you enter the grey area of undefined behavior.  You can work around this by instantiating the Spy yourself.  Note that the Spy annotation is retained even though you are instantiating and telling Mockito to wrap it in a Spy yourself.
@InjectMocks
@Spy
PermissionDTOConverter permissionDTOConverter = Mockito.spy(new PermissionDTOConverter());

It appears that you do not have to define the Spy inline so long as you create the object that you want to spy upon.  So the following should also work.
@InjectMocks
@Spy
PermissionDTOConverter permissionDTOConverter = new PermissionDTOConverter();

In sum, the following could work for you.
public class UpdateFileSecurityServiceTest {
  @InjectMocks
  private UpdateFileSecurityService  SUT;
  @Mock
  private FolderRepository folderRepository;
  @InjectMocks
  @Spy
  private PermissionDTOConverter permissionDTOConverter = new PermissionDTOConverter();
 
  @Before private void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.init(this);
  }
}


It makes no sense to have @Spy and at the same time assign the field with = Mockito.spy.

@knittl I've used this approach and it works.  However, I tried a few other things and found that you can also just create the instance you want to wrap and it also appears to work.  I'll update the answer.  In either case, this is non-standard usage of Mockito so it could cease to function in future releases.
